# Weighted mean and SD calculation for $1000$ sample

Tags: statistics

If certain sheets of paper have a mean weight of 10 g each, with a standard deviation of $0.05$ g, what are the mean weight and standard deviation of a pack of $10, 000$ sheets?

Comment: Welcome to Stackexchange. Simple "Here's my exercise, solve it for me" posts usually get few responses. It is better to say what you understand about the problem, what you've tried so far, etc. Something to both show you are part of the learning experience and to help us guide you to the appropriate help. You can consult [this link](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/q/9959) for further guidance.

Comment: Mean: $10000\mu$; For the standard deviation, *if the weights are independent*, $\sqrt{10000}\,\sigma$.

Answer (score 1):

We see that for a given sheet of paper's weight $X$, $E[X] = 10$ and
$V[X] = (.05)^2.$ Hence, assuming that the weights on each paper are
independent, then we are dealing with random variable
$Y = 10000X,$
$$E[Y] = E[10000X],$$
which by linearity of expectation
$$=10000E[X] = 10000 \times 10 = 100000.$$
We see that
$$SD(Y) = \sqrt{V[Y]} = \sqrt{V[10000X]},$$
which by quadratic-ness in Variance
$$=\sqrt{(10000)^2V[X]}
= \sqrt{(10000 \times .05)^2} = \sqrt{(500)^2} = 500.$$